# NRPE Socket timeout via NRPE, works as nrpe user

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, nagios, nrpe

nrpe on azure server - `nrpe-srvr`, user `nrpe`, executing script `/usr/local/naemon/libexec/check_curl_http.php` I'll call it `script`

Desired output after `./script -U www.google.com`:

```
Page OK: HTTP Status Code 200 - 11099 bytest in 0.** seconds | time=0.059 size=11099
```

I achieve the above output by running the script from `root` or `nrpe`

Running `sudo -u nrpe ./script -U www.google.com` returns:

> Error in opening page! Err:Failed to connect to [ipv6 addr] Network is
>   unreachable

However running `su - nrpe -c './script -U www.google.com'` works with the desired result.

Naemon reports:

> CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 30 secs

Other NRPE checks to the same host are working, so I think it's something to do with user execution of this specific script. I did have a deny from `SELinux`, but adjusted the context. Removing the context and setting SELinux to permissive yielded the same error. Enabled NRPE Log files, with debugging, but other than `Running command` it doesn't really reveal much. There is a:

```
WARNING: my_system() seteuid(0): Operation not permitted
```

in the logs, but looking at the support documentation that is "Normal" behavior.

Comment: Try also run that script in verbose mode.

Comment: I think the script is executing fine. I actually managed to get it to work as another user using `su - nrpe - c './script -u www.google.com'` fine. So I think the script it ok. NRPE execution is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this just in case someone else has this issue, and I'll tag Azure / AWS.

Essentially, cloud providers (mostly) have an internal proxy that is stored in an environment variable `http_proxy` && `https_proxy`. NRPE by default doesn't use load environment variables. Now I don't know if there is an option for it (it's mentioned in the docs that there is a bug when using uid instead of username (was using username)) however it's simple enough to call proxy for checks like this.